# Deploying Django on Windows server 2019 using xampp gives ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_socket'\r

Tags: django, apache, xampp, mod-wsgi

I am trying to host a django application on Windows Server 2019 using XAMPP and after going through all the settings necessary for the app to run, I get an Internal Server Error.

Here's my setup:

Running on venv, doing a pip freeze gives:

```
(envcrm)
DECRM@CRM2 MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/crm
$ pip freeze
asgiref==3.6.0
Django==4.1.5
mod-wsgi==4.9.4
mysqlclient==2.1.1
sqlparse==0.4.3
tzdata==2022.7
```

Django App is in `C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\decrm`

Directory Structure:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\crm
|--decrm      -> python project
|--envcrm     -> virtual environment
|--mydecrm    -> app
|--static     -> static folder for the apps
|--templates  -> templates folder for the apps
|--users      -> app
```

Also placed MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR in the environment variables to be able to do a successful
`pip install mod_wsgi`

As for the `httpd.conf`, here's my setting for WSGI:

```
LoadFile "C:/Users/DECRM/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python311.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "C:/xampp/htdocs/crm/envcrm/Lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp311-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "C:/xampp/htdocs/crm/envcrm"
WSGIScriptAlias / "c:/xampp/htdocs/crm/decrm/wsgi.py"
WSGIPythonPath "c:/xampp/htdocs/crm"

<Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/crm/decrm/">
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

Alias /static "c:/xampp/htdocs/crm/static/"
<Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/crm/static/">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

with this, I get an Internal Server Error with these on the error logs:

```
[Wed Jan 25 19:18:33.645848 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 2060] [client ::1:51675] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_socket'\r
[Wed Jan 25 19:18:33.694850 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 2076] [client ::1:51674] mod_wsgi (pid=6720): Failed to exec Python script file 'C:/xampp/htdocs/crm/decrm/wsgi.py'., referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Jan 25 19:18:33.694850 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 2076] [client ::1:51674] mod_wsgi (pid=6720): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/xampp/htdocs/crm/decrm/wsgi.py'., referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Jan 25 19:18:33.697847 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 2076] [client ::1:51674] Traceback (most recent call last):\r, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Jan 25 19:18:33.698851 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 2076] [client ::1:51674]   File "C:/xampp/htdocs/crm/decrm/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>\r, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Jan 25 19:18:33.698851 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 2076] [client ::1:51674]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application\r, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Jan 25 19:18:33.698851 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 2076] [client ::1:51674]   File "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\crm\\envcrm\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\wsgi.py", line 2, in <module>\r, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Jan 25 19:18:33.698851 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 2076] [client ::1:51674]     from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler\r, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Jan 25 19:18:33.698851 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 2076] [client ::1:51674]   File "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\crm\\envcrm\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\handlers\\wsgi.py", line 3, in <module>\r, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Jan 25 19:18:33.698851 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 2076] [client ::1:51674]     from django.conf import settings\r, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Jan 25 19:18:33.698851 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 2076] [client ::1:51674]   File "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\crm\\envcrm\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>\r, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Jan 25 19:18:33.698851 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 2076] [client ::1:51674]     from django.utils.deprecation import RemovedInDjango50Warning\r, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Jan 25 19:18:33.698851 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 2076] [client ::1:51674]   File "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\crm\\envcrm\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\utils\\deprecation.py", line 1, in <module>\r, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Jan 25 19:18:33.698851 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 2076] [client ::1:51674]     import asyncio\r, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Jan 25 19:18:33.698851 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 2076] [client ::1:51674]   File "C:\\Users\\DECRM\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\asyncio\\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>\r, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Jan 25 19:18:33.698851 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 2076] [client ::1:51674]     from .base_events import *\r, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Jan 25 19:18:33.698851 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 2076] [client ::1:51674]   File "C:\\Users\\DECRM\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\asyncio\\base_events.py", line 23, in <module>\r, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Jan 25 19:18:33.698851 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 2076] [client ::1:51674]     import socket\r, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Jan 25 19:18:33.698851 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 2076] [client ::1:51674]   File "C:\\Users\\DECRM\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\socket.py", line 51, in <module>\r, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Jan 25 19:18:33.698851 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 2076] [client ::1:51674]     import _socket\r, referer: http://localhost/
[Wed Jan 25 19:18:33.698851 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 6720:tid 2076] [client ::1:51674] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_socket'\r, referer: http://localhost/
```

I just don't know where to look from here, especially for the `_socket` module.

Other details:

```
Apache/2.4.54 (Win64)
mod_wsgi/4.9.4
Python/3.11
```

Anything I might have missed or have been setting incorrectly? Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The "_socket.pyd" file has been installed in the Python DLLs folder.
So please modify the "wsgi.py" file to append the DLLs folder to the "sys.path" as follows.

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append("C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python3xx/DLLs")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
```

(continued..)

*Because enable the "from ~ import" command, Please append the "sys.path.append()" function above the sentense of "from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application".